# Can you call a variable value with web3.js, without writing the function in solidity?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, nodejs

I have used remix and I can see that whenever I create a public variable, it also creates a function for the variable and when you press it, it shows the variable value but, when I want to call a variable using `web3.js` the function should have been written from solidity that returns the variable value, in order to call it from `contract.methods.<function>`.

My question is: is there a way to call any variable inside a smart contract, without actually writing the function that returns the value in solidity?

Comment: Yes u can, every variable (private or public) is sorted publicly but u just need to find it

Comment: If the variable is public it will have automatically a get method. use the variable name after .methods